# Error 8024401C during the download of the updates on the Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012

I've started the updates download on Windows Server 2012. The download process fails with the error message 8024401C. Accoring to the entries in the internet on the support pages, the proxy server should be the matter of the failure. Idon't have any possibility to access to the internet without proxy. Is it possible to download the updates anywhay?

Comment: Did you see this? http://faultbucket.ca/2012/08/windows-server-2012-windows-update-error-0x80240440/

Answer (score 2):

Answer from [Chopper3](https://serverfault.com/users/1435/chopper3)'s link:

A Firewall rule on the Sonicwall caused the issue.

> Then I thought to look at my Sonicwall NSA 2400; we have the
> Application Control enabled, and this has been known to cause strange
> network connectivity issues even when not expected so I’ve just by
> default started checking here.
>
> Unsurprisingly this turned out to be the problem. The strange thing
> is, the AppControl rule that was blocking the traffic isn’t visible in
> the list of applications; only through the logging did I find it.
>
> Turns out the rule “Non-SSL Traffic over SSL port” is blocking this
> Windows Update traffic. Setting the Block option to Disabled for this
> rule allows Windows Update to work properly.

[Source](http://faultbucket.ca/2012/08/windows-server-2012-windows-update-error-0x80240440/)